# FTDI based Xilinx JTAG

Tags: fpga, jtag, ftdi, xilinx

I have some boards with Xilinx Spartan 3 FPGAs, I would like to upload new bitstreams over JTAG. I was planning on using [UrJTAG](http://urjtag.sourceforge.net/book/index.html).

I already have a couple of [FTDI based JTAG adapters](http://www.olimex.com/dev/arm-usb-ocd.html) for ARM targets - can these be used?

They run at 3V3, I read that the Xilinx JTAG is at 2V5 will this be a problem?

Alternatively, I have a few FTDI FT232s, is there a simple cable I could build?

Comment: Xilinx official support for this use case starting in 2022: https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2022.1-English/ug908-vivado-programming-debugging/Programming-FTDI-Devices-for-Vivado-Hardware-Manager-Support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want a look at [Xilinx app note 453](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Spartan-Family-FPGAs/Spartan3-JTAG-interface-3-3V/m-p/51026), title "The 3.3V Configuration of Spartan-3 FPGAs". Basically the advice is putting resistors in series to limit the current through the protection diodes, and one over the 2.5V to sink the remaining current. Using level shifting circuitry instead would also work.

Comment: Thanks. Direct link to PDF http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp453.pdf